# Testing two-tailed p-values using Stouffer's approach

Tags: hypothesis-testing, combining-p-values

About combining multiple test statistics, [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Fisher%27s_method#Relation_to_Stouffer.27s_Z-score_method) says

> This Z-score (for the overall meta-analysis) is appropriate for
>   one-sided right-tailed p-values; minor modifications can be made if
>   two-sided or left-tailed p-values are being analyzed.

What are those minor modifications?

Comment: modified the wikipedia page aligned with answers below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) If two-sided p-values are being analyzed, you use the two-sided p-value in the calculation of the $Z_i$.  The two-sided p-value is $\tilde{p}_i = p_i/2$.

2) If left-tailed p-values are used, you use $1-p_i$ instead of $p_i$ in the calculation of the $Z_i$.

Comment: I don’t get the rationale of your definition of $\widetilde p_i$. I would have put $Z_i = \Phi^{-1}(1-p_i/2)$, and use as a score $\sum Z_i^2$ which follows a χ²(k) distribution.

Comment: @ElvisJaggerAbdul-Jabbar: You are correct, I was suffering a momentary fit of stupidity.  I've edited the answer appropriately.

Comment: I was apparently suffering the same kind of syndrome, as I now don’t understand why I wanted to take the same of squared $Z_i$. I think your answer is now perfect (+1).

Comment: If the test is two-sided, then low p-value can correspond as well to `Z=10` as to `Z=-10`. Why are always keeping the sign positive?